# PHP Array and foreach Combination calculation

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

In a quiz app, I am taking user answer using a form. I am retrieving correct answer from database table. I want to compare the correct answer with the user's answer and count how many answer was right and how many answer was wrong.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="question" class="" action="quiz_ans.php" method="post">
    <table id="quiz-question" align="center" class="row-border compact order-column stripe">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="NumberofQuestions" id="NumberofQuestions" value="<?php echo $NumberofQuestions; ?>">
        <thead>
            <?php
                if($QuizQuestions) {
                    $i=1;
                    foreach($QuizQuestions as $row):
              ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $i; ?>. <?php echo $row->Question; ?>
                    <br>
                <?php if(isset($row->Screenshot)) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->Screenshot); ?>" alt="test" height="300" width="980">
                <?php } ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(isset($row->Option1)) { ?>
            <tr class="info">
                <td><input type="radio" name="AnswerId[<?php echo $row->Id; ?>]" value="0"><?php echo $row->Option1; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($row->Option2)) { ?>
            <tr class="info">
                <td><input type="radio" name="AnswerId[<?php echo $row->Id; ?>]" value="1"> <?php echo $row->Option2; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($row->Option3)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="AnswerId[<?php echo $row->Id; ?>]" value="2"> <?php echo $row->Option3; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($row->Option4)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="AnswerId[<?php echo $row->Id; ?>]" value="3"><?php echo $row->Option4; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="AnswerReason">Why?</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="AnswerReason[]" id="AnswerReason" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <?php if(isset($row->Id)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="QuestionId[]" id="QuestionId" value="<?php echo $row->Id; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>


        </tbody>

    <?php
        $i++;
      endforeach;
      }
    ?>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

I am getting the user answer from the form submit:

```
$NumberofQuestions = $_POST['NumberofQuestions'];
$ans = implode("", $_POST['AnswerId']);
```

I am retreiving the correct answer from the database table:

```
 try {
   $sql = "CALL spQuizAnswers(:quiz_num)";
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':quiz_num', $quiz_num, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
   $stmt->execute();
   $QuizAns=$stmt->fetchAll();
   $stmt->closeCursor();
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
   die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I am comparing the user's answer and the correct answer:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$NumberofQuestions; $i++) {
    if($QuizAns) {
        foreach($QuizAns as $row):
            if($row->CorrectAns == $ans[$i]){
                $right++;
            } elseif($ans[$i] == 4){
                $not_answered++;
            } else {
                $wrong++;
            }

        endforeach;
    }
}

$CorrectAnswer = $right;
$WrongAnswer = $wrong;
$NotAnswered = $not_answered;
$TotalQuestion = $right+$wrong+$not_answered;
```

It does not give correct calculation. **For 5 questions it gives $TotalQuestion=25.** 
How can I achieve the correct calculation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, Your form has: `<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="NumberofQuestions" id="NumberofQuestions" value="<?php echo $NumberofQuestions; ?>">` and then you say your using `$NumberofQuestions = $_POST['NumberofQuestions'];`. But you put `$NumberofQuestions` as value in your `$_POST['NumberofQuestions']`. What would be the initial state then?

Comment: @Loko $NumberofQuestions is just how many questions there are in the form. Let's say for a quiz there are 5 questions, so $NumberofQuestions=5. I get it when I fetch the questions from database like so: try {
    $sql = "CALL spQuizQuestions(:quiz_num)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':quiz_num', $quiz_num, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
    $stmt->execute();
    $QuizQuestions=$stmt->fetchAll();
    $NumberofQuestions=$stmt->rowCount();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
}

Comment: If there are 5 questions then there are 5 answers from the query and the `for` loop loops 5 times and each of those 5 times the `foreach` loops 5 times.  You need to match the `ids`.

Comment: @ AbraCadaver How do I match the ids?